# Multiple aspects template class specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, aop

**Context**

I am currently writting some Aspect Oriented code in C++. I have the following class hierarchy :

```
class Base                   { virtual void doSmth() {/* generic stuff */ } };
class DerivedA : public Base { virtual void doSmth() {/* specific DerivedA stuff */} };
class DerivedB : public Base { virtual void doSmth() {/* specific DerivedB stuff */} };
```

I have defined some aspects classes to add some features to the classes described above :

```
template <class I>
class Aspect1 : public I
{
  void doSmth() { I::doSmth(); doSmthMore(); }
  void doSmthMore() { /* do something specific to Aspect1 */ }
};


template <class I>
class Aspect2 : public I
{
  void doSmth() { I::doSmth(); doSmthMore(); }
  void doSmthMore() { /* do something specific to Aspect2 */ }
};
```

In specific cases (`Aspect1` over `DerivedA` and `DerivedB`) I have the following specialization of `Aspect1` :

```
template <>
class Aspect1< DerivedA > : public DerivedA
{
  void doSmth() { I::doSmth(); doSmthMore(); doSmthMoreA(); }
  void doSmthMore()  { /* do something specific to Aspect1 */ }
  void doSmthMoreA() { /* do something specific to Aspect1 for DerivedA*/ }
};
// Idem for Aspect1//DerivedB
```

---

**My question**

How can I be sure that the specialization of `Aspect1` for, let's say `DerivedA`, will be compiled even if I type it with `Aspect2<DerivedA>` as template parameter ?

i.e. in a configuration file :

```
typedef Aspect2<Aspect1<DerivedA> > > ClassToBeUsed; // This is OK

typedef Aspect1<Aspect2<DerivedA> > > ClassToBeUsed; // This is not (Aspect1 specialization for DerivedA is not compiled)
```

One possibility could be that any class derived from DerivedA use the specialisation Aspect1 . Is there any way to do that (maybe using some `boost::is_base_of` and `boost::enable_if`) ?

I thought that I could use some `typedef DerivedA AspectBase;` in the `DerivedA` body, but I don't see how to specialize the `Aspect1` template class over a typedef inside the template class argument.

Thanks for your suggestions !

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the only way you can be sure is if the type `Aspect1<DerivedA>` is used. If it is used, it will be compiled, otherwise not.

Comment: Is there no way to "forward" the definition Aspect1< ANYTYPE_DERIVED_FROM_DERIVEDA > to Aspect1<DerivedA> ?